# LocalStackContainer integration testing a lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, spock, testcontainers, localstack

Is there a way we can (integration) test a Lambda for AWS using testcontainers & the following LocalStackContainer:

```
new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse('localstack/localstack:0.11.6'))
    .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.LAMBDA)
```

Specifically, how do I "upload" the Lambda to the locally running service, so that I can then trigger & test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to setup Localstack and a MySql testcontainer (in groovy spock) like so:

```
  @Shared
  public static Network network = Network.newNetwork()

  @Shared
  @ClassRule
  public static MySQLContainer mySql = new MySQLContainer(DockerImageName.parse('mysql:5.7'))
    .withNetwork(network)
    .withNetworkAliases(MY_SQL_HOST_NAME) as MySQLContainer

  @Shared
  @ClassRule
  public static LocalStackContainer localStack = new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse('localstack/localstack:0.11.6'))
    .withServices(SQS, LAMBDA, CLOUDWATCH, DYNAMODB, KMS, STS, IAM)
    .withNetwork(network)
    .withEnv('LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK', network.name)
    .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forHostPath(new File('the jar file').path), '/opt/code/localstack/lambda.jar')
    .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource('seed.yaml'), '/init/seed.yaml')
```

- This sets up a bridged network so that the two containers can
  communicate with each other. Also setting LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK allows the lambda to communicate with MySql, SQS etc.
- The lambda jar file is copied to the container (withCopyFileToContainer)
- I also needed KMS, so seed.yaml initialises it (see Local KMS documentation)

Once the container is up and running the lambda can be deployed using awslocal and standard CLI commands:

```
    def result = localStack.execInContainer(
      'awslocal', 'lambda', 'create-function',
      '--function-name', 'lambda-name',
      '--runtime', 'java8',
      '--handler', 'uk.co.blah.blah.Handler',
      '--role', 'arn:aws:iam::123456:role/irrelevant',
      '--zip-file', 'fileb://lambda.jar',
      '--environment', "Variables={MY_SQL_USERNAME=${mySql.username},MY_SQL_PASSWORD=${encryptedDbPassword},PLATFORM_DB_URL=${"jdbc:mysql://${MY_SQL_HOST_NAME}:3306"}," +
        "AWS_REGION=${localStack.region}}"
    )
```

Finally, the lambda can be manually triggered in tests like so:

```
localStack.execInContainer('awslocal', 'lambda', 'invoke', '--function-name', 'lambda-name', 'output0.json')
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the `LocalStackContainer` is started, you can execute commands inside the container to set up your infrastructure. LocalStack provides the `awslocal` binary to create any AWS resources.

Inside your test, you can then have a `@BeforeAll` step where you use your container reference and create everything.

The following example does this for S3 and SQS (reference from this [blog post](https://rieckpil.de/test-spring-applications-using-aws-with-testcontainers-and-localstack/)):

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
public class YourLocalStackIT {
 
  @Container
  static LocalStackContainer localStack = new LocalStackContainer("0.11.6")
    .withServices(S3, SQS)
    .withEnv("DEFAULT_REGION", "eu-central-1");
 
  @BeforeAll
  static void beforeAll() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    localStack.execInContainer("awslocal", "sqs", "create-queue", "--queue-name", QUEUE_NAME);
    localStack.execInContainer("awslocal", "s3", "mb", "s3://" + BUCKET_NAME);
  }
 
  private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "order-event-test-queue";
  private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "order-event-test-bucket";
 
  // ... actual test
}
```

You can use this as a template to now prepare your AWS Lambda function.

Regarding the source code upload, I guess it makes sense to mount or copy the `.zip` version of your Lambda also to your container to then access it inside.

A NodeJS lambda could be created like the following:

```
awslocal lambda create-function \
    --region eu-central1 \
    --function-name your-api \
    --runtime nodejs8.10 \
    --handler lambda.apiHandler \
    --memory-size 128 \
    --zip-file fileb://api-handler.zip
```

Comment: Thanks @rieckpil that looks like a good starting point! I'll try it out!